# Создание окна в Windows без WinAPI, можно ли так сделать или нет

Tags: c++, windows

Окна в Windows создаются только через WinAPI, или есть какие-то другие способы?

Comment: Есть много библиотек, которые используют WinAPI как обвертку - через них - можно (VCL,  DotNet-forms, QT). Какая у вас цель, с какой целью вам нужно создать окно без WinAPI? Может вам нужно что-то вроде DrawFrameControl?

Comment: @nick_n_a да просто думал насчет своего графического движка на C++, и размышлял о том, что все равно придется с Canvas формы работать через WinAPI. Но, мб я чего-то не знал, и можно без WinAPI обойтись было

Comment: Ну... я думаю что графический движок лучше строить на WinAPI, а не на другом графическом движке.

Comment: @Faimen чтобы просто рисовать на экране, можно использовать в винде целых три подсистемы GDI, DirectX, OpenGL. Раскройте тогда, что значит "не используя WINAPI"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Невозмножно. Все, что происходит в любой операционной системе, работающей в защищенном режиме с аппаратной защитой памяти и инструкций ЦП, а это все современные мейнстримные, происходит **только** через API этой системы.

*За исключением всевозможных хаков, но это уже отдельный вопрос.*

Comment: @gdb а разве в win нельзя дернуть окно через ogl? или там тож WinAPI?

Comment: Чтобы OpenGL в его WGL-инкарнации работал, нужно создать контекст. Контекст можно создать только располагая DC окна, который можно получить только через WINAPI

Comment: Ну или нахачить)

Comment: А как же вариант написать свой драйвер в режиме ядра?